# awk with duplicate values

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

**File:**

```
22 Hello
22 Hi
1  What
34 Where
21 is
44 How
44 are
44 you
```

**Desired Output:**

```
22 HelloHi
1  What
34 Where
21 is
44 Howareyou
```

**If there are duplicate values in first field($1) the second field should have appended text**

How to achieve this using awk?

Thanks

Comment: I think it will be *way* easier to use e.g. Python for this. Are you sure you intend to use awk?

Comment: Yes i'm definitely looking for awk solution

Comment: @UliKöhler : are you kidding!? :-) Looking forward to you answer in Python. I will vote for any working answer you care to post. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Here you go ;-)

Comment: I think this is *way* easier in [tag:awk]. As is everything. :-)

Comment: fun question, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '!($1 in a){a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a{a[$1]=a[$1] $2} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
22 HelloHi
44 Howareyou
34 Where
21 is
1 What
```

**EDIT:** To preserve the order:

```
awk '!($1 in a){b[++n]=$1; a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a{a[$1] = a[$1] $2}
        END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i], a[b[i]]}' file
22 HelloHi
1 What
34 Where
21 is
44 Howareyou
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible if the solution is in the same order as in file

Comment: the order it is in desired output

Answer (score 10):

```
$ awk '
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $1 } 
{ str[$1] = str[$1] $2 }
END{
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        print key, str[key]
    }
}
' file
22 HelloHi
1 What
34 Where
21 is
44 Howareyou
```

Answer (score 5):

To maintain the order, you need to keep track of it:

```
awk '
    ! seen[$1]++ {order[++n] = $1}
    {value[$1] = value[$1] $2}
    END {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print order[i], value[order[i]]}
' <<END
22 Hello
22 Hi
1  What
34 Where
21 is
44 How
44 are
44 you
END
```

```
22 HelloHi
1 What
34 Where
21 is
44 Howareyou
```

If you know the values in the 1st column are contiguous, as in your sample text, then:

```
awk '
    prev != $1 {printf "%s%s ", sep, $1; sep=RS} 
    {printf "%s", $2; prev = $1} 
    END {print ""}
'
```

---

A couple of other approaches:

```
perl -lane '
        push @keys, $F[0] unless grep {$_ eq $F[0]} @keys;
        $val{$F[0]} .= $F[1]
    } END {
        print "$_ $val{$_}" for @keys
' file
```

and, reaching way into the niche zone

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
while {[gets stdin line] != -1} {dict append val {*}$line}
dict for {k v} $val {puts "$k $v"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution in Python, as requested by @shellter:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

with open("file") as infile:
    d = defaultdict(str)
    #Build dictionary of values
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        k, _, v = line.partition(" ")
        d[k] += v
    #Print everything
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        print k,v
```

Note that the ordering is not preserved in this solution. Here is an alternate solution that provides *exactly* the desired output:

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open("file") as infile:
    d = defaultdict(str)
    orig_order = []
    #Build dictionary of values
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        k, _, v = line.partition(" ")
        d[k] += v
        #Add to original order if not seen yet
        if not k in orig_order:
            orig_order.append(k)
    #Print everything
    for k in orig_order:
        print k, d[k]
```

Note that these are quickly-crafted solution, I am sure it is possible without too much effort to either make them shorter or more flexible.

Comment: You owe the guy :) @shellter

Comment: +1, .... but .... 'I think it will be way easier to use e.g. Python for this', .... well ... I guess it depends on your perspective. Fun to read thru and get a sense of basic python txt processing. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @shellter It does ;-) took me about 45 seconds for the non-ordered version, plus about the same for the ordered version. Using list/dict comprehension, I assume one could reduce the size by ~80%. I think the main advantage here is that it can be reused in a larger application. But I should note that I'm not into *awk* at all, which certainly influences my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

if the order is not important, this will work:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]$2}; END {for (i in a) {print a[i]}}' file
```

.. and if order *is* important:

```
awk '{if (!a[$1]) b[++i]=$1;a[$1]=a[$1]$2}; END {for (j=1;j<i;j++) {print a[b[j]]}}' file
```